# How to mask variable in Jenkins console so I can avoid to leak my token?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

In my Jenkins pipeline, I made the `withCredentials` plugin as a function so I can pass variable to retrieve different secret and make my stage pipeline clean. Below is my code.

```groovy
def getCredentialsString(dsl, credentialsId) {
    def r;
    dsl.withCredentials([string(credentialsId: credentialsId, variable: 'CredentialsString')]) {
        r = "${env.CredentialsString}"
    }
    return r
}
```

stage pipeline, `my-jenkins-token` and `my-jenkins-api-token` are Secrets in jenkins to store my API token. I hidden necessary commands and show as below.

```
def project_token = credentials.getCredentialsString(this, "my-jenkins-token")
def api_token = credentials.getCredentialsString(this, "my-jenkins-api-token")

sh "mvn -Dsettings.security=${mavenSecuritySetting} -DprojectToken=${project_token} -DapiToken=${api_token} -Dcommit=${COMMIT_ID} -s ${mavenSetting}"
```

The question is, if I choose to separate `withCredentials`, the token will print out as plain text and I want to know a way to mask the variable. I can make the variable as ENV variable as long as it can help to mask output in console.

Comment: Why not to run sh inside withCredentials?

Comment: @daggett, because I want to wrap the withCredentials as function so I can dynamically retrieve the credentials and also avoid blocks.

Comment: Put the secret into Env. And don't interpolate it on the level of groovy.

Comment: @daggett. Thanks for your advice, I will try that. But I am currently think that if there is anyway that I can wrap my credential function smarter so I can directly run the job in function and also pass credential ID variable.

Comment: The credentials aren’t protected once you take it out of the withCredentials block. As mentioned above, the correct way is to execute your logic inside the withCredentialsBlock. I do not see any gain by wrapping it around another custom method.

Comment: @RamKamath, if you put the command in the block. First, you will need to pass all the credential ID in the list and they will not easy to read once you got numbers of credentials. Second, I want to pass credential ID as variable so I can use the same pipeline in other jobs, don't need to change the credential ID inside the block. That's the gain.

Comment: I would recommend passing both credentilasId and the closure in that case.  `def executeWithCredentials(String credentialsId){ withCredentials([string(credentialsId: credentialsId, variable: 'CredentialsString')]){ body()}}` and the call would be `executeWithCredentials('credId'){ // your code that requires credentials}`

Comment: @RamKamath, that sounds good. But I tried to avoid multiple block closure. Do you have any idea that we can pass multiple credential ID dynamically into the function? I'm not sure whether groovy can do it.

Comment: Added an aswer. Hope that helps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235748/discussion-between-ram-kamath-and-t-r).

Answer (score 2):

Getting access to the value of a secret outside the `withCredentils` block defeats the purpose of storing the secrets safely. I would recommend using the below approach if you have a dynamic range of credentials.

```
node('master'){
    Map creds= [slack_token: 'Slack', aws_token: 'AWS'] // key is the local variable and value is the credentialsId from jenkins store
    runWithCredentials(creds){
        echo "${slack_token} and ${aws_token}"
    }
}

def runWithCredentials(Map credentials, def body){
    List credBlock = []
    credentials.each {credValue, credId ->
        credBlock.add(string(credentialsId: credId, variable: credValue))
    }
    withCredentials(credBlock){
        body()
    }
}
```